# Does AngularJS have any weakness (compared to JQuery)?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Are there any thing that AngularJS is not good at but JQuery is the better choice?

One thing I can think of is adding/removing DOM nodes.
Any thing else?

==============================

I should ask the question in a different way: under which kind of situation, I should choose JQuery but not AnguarJS?

Comment: There are many comparisions if you search the internet. For exmaple - https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should must know about framework vs library,

- **Framework:** Which describes how to show your code. Its like a code-template having MVC or MVVM architecture. Examples, "AngularJS", "Backbone", "requireJS", "socketIO".
- **Library:** Its like a toolkit and/or a single file having all the utility functions which can be used to play with your DOM elements event or to manipulate them. You can add.remove elements dynamically, add/remove CSS classes, styles or elements, etc.  You can say the *flour is ready to make chapati or paratha whatever you like*. Examples "jQuery", "MooTools", "YUI".

So, clear from the difference, you need a library like `jQuery` not a framework like `Angular`.